# Why use "HEAD:master" instead of just "master" in a "git push origin"

Tags: git

I am synching multiple git repositories. It's challenging; I can sync just the diffs easily, but if I want to sync changes I need to do pulls and pushes, and (sometimes) resolve the conflicts locally.

Sometimes, when I do a `git push`, git tells me to use:

```
git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
```

which usually becomes:

```
git push origin HEAD:master
```

However, this also works:

```
git push origin master
```

So what's the difference? Why do I need the `HEAD:` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run

```
git push origin X:Y
```

What happens is that you push something locally named X to the remote name Y. HEAD is an alias for whatever is currently checked out. If you currently have master checked out, then this is equivalent to

```
git push origin master:master
```

If you have a different branch checked out, you get different behavior. You do not need HEAD and I would avoid using it when pushing.

If you omit `:master` and just run:

```
git push origin master
```

It will use `master` as the default branch name on the remote, unless you have configured it differently.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps HEAD: is needed if you might be in an older place in the revision history? (like you did a checkout of a previous commit?)

Comment: FYI) `git push origin HEAD` is equivalent to `git push origin master` if `HEAD` points to the local branch `master`. Note that it could be confusing because, many times, the local and remote branches use the same name `master` (or `main` nowadays).

Answer (score 0):

Would this be more clearly worded as:

If you omit master: and just run:

git push origin master

It will use master as the default branch name on the local, unless you have configured it differently.